# UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found

Tags: java, android, android-ndk

I know this question has been asked to death so far, but none of the solutions I read worked for me, so I thought I'd see if anyone can come up with a new answer.

Here is the Java code:

```
private native int nativeVideoPlayerMain(String fileName, int loop,int audioFileType, 
        int skipFrames, int rgb565, int yuvRgbAsm, int skipBidirFrames, int queueSizeMin, int queueSizeMax, int queueSizeTotal, int queueSizeAudio,
        int fastMode, int debugMode, int syncType, int seekDuration, int ffmpegFlags);
```

in package com.example.player and class DemoRenderer.

Here is the native code definition:

```
       extern C_LINKAGE int
       Java_com_example_player_DemoRenderer_nativeVideoPlayerMain(JNIEnv* env, 
       jobject obj,
       jstring jfileName, 
       jint loopAfterPlay, 
       jint audioFileType,
       jint skipFrames,
       jint rgb565,
       jint yuvRgbAsm,
       jint skipBidirFrames,
       jint queueSizeMin,
       jint queueSizeMax,
       jint totalQueueSize,
       jint audioQueueSize,
       jint fastMode,
       jint debugMode,
       jint syncType,
       jint seekDuration,
       jint ffmpegFlags)
    {
    jboolean isCopy;

int argc = 1;

    int my_loop_after_play;
    int my_audio_file_type;
    int my_skip_frames;
    int my_rgb_565;
    int my_yuv_rgb_asm;
    int my_skip_bidir_frames;
    int my_queue_size_min;
    int my_queue_size_max;
    int my_total_queue_size;
    int my_audio_queue_size;
    int my_fast_mode;
    int my_debug_mode;
    int my_sync_type;
    int my_seek_duration;
    int my_ffmpeg_flags;

    #ifdef BROOV_C
    const char *fileString = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, jfileName, &isCopy);
    #else
    const char *fileString     = env->GetStringUTFChars(jfileName, &isCopy);
    #endif
    char lclFileName[FILE_NAME_SIZE];

    strncpy(lclFileName, fileString, FILE_NAME_SIZE);

    #ifdef BROOV_C
    (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, jfileName, fileString);
    #else
    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(jfileName, fileString);
    #endif

char *argv[] = { lclFileName };

    my_loop_after_play = loopAfterPlay;
    my_audio_file_type = audioFileType;
    my_skip_frames = skipFrames;
    my_rgb_565 = rgb565;
    my_yuv_rgb_asm = yuvRgbAsm;
    my_skip_bidir_frames = skipBidirFrames;
    my_queue_size_min = queueSizeMin;
    my_queue_size_max = queueSizeMax;
    my_total_queue_size= totalQueueSize;
    my_audio_queue_size= audioQueueSize;
    my_fast_mode = fastMode;
    my_debug_mode = debugMode;
    my_sync_type= syncType;
    my_seek_duration= seekDuration;
    my_ffmpeg_flags = ffmpegFlags;

    return video_player_main(argc, argv, my_loop_after_play, my_audio_file_type, 
                       my_skip_frames, my_rgb_565, my_yuv_rgb_asm, 
                       my_skip_bidir_frames, my_queue_size_min, my_queue_size_max,    
    my_total_queue_size, my_audio_queue_size, my_fast_mode, my_debug_mode,  
    my_sync_type, my_seek_duration, my_ffmpeg_flags);

    }
```

Other methods from this file are found and successfully executed, but this one refuses to do so. I've ran ndk-build clean and ndk-build several times, but the method cannot be found. If anyone has any suggestions, please share :)

EDIT:
Thats the error message:

```
W/dalvikvm(18569): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41c94ba8)
E/AndroidRuntime(18569): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread
E/AndroidRuntime(18569): Process: com.example.player, PID: 18569
E/AndroidRuntime(18569): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: com.example.player.DemoRenderer.nativeVideoPlayerMain:(Ljava/lang/String;IIIIIIIIIIIIIII)I
E/AndroidRuntime(18569):    at com.example.player.DemoRenderer.nativeVideoPlayerMain(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(18569):    at com.example.player.DemoRenderer.onDrawFrame(DemoRenderer.java:43)
E/AndroidRuntime(18569):    at com.example.player.GLSurfaceView_SDL$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView_SDL.java:944)
W/ActivityManager(  509):   Force finishing activity com.example.player/.PlayerActivity
```

Update:
As I was trying to verify the function is indeed loaded in its library, I discovered I don't know which library this is. What I mean is this:

- When I do this: grep -R "nativePlayerInit" * -n (that's another function in the same file that I have no problems loading) I get these among others:

Binary file libs/armeabi-v7a/libapplication.so matches

Binary file obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libapplication.so matches

Binary file obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/application/src/native_main.o matches

- When I do this for nativeVideoPlayerMain however, I get no static objects matches.
- The weirdest thing is I get an equivalent result when I grep the files of the original and working project.

So, to sum it all up: how is it possible for the original project to be working correctly, when the function doesn't seem to be loaded into any of its static objects? Can it have static objects somewhere out of its directory?

Comment: What's the exact error that you get?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21480981/jni-exception-in-thread-awt-eventqueue-0-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror. See my answer there. Same problem: same solution.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but if I don't think javah will fix the problem, because I have no problems with other functions, only with this particular one.

Comment: Do you load the library in Java using static{System.loadLibrary("libname");} ?

Comment: You have a problem with this one because you've changed the package or class or method name. The evidence is right there in the stack trace. Re-running javah etc. will certainly fix it.

Comment: Well I just created a new project, with the original package and class names - issue remains the same. @user2359247, yes, I've included it.

Comment: Always a good idea to make sure it's actually there and visible.  Pull the shared lib out of the installation directory (/data/data/<package>...) with `adb pull`, then examine the symbol table with `arm-eabi-nm -D` (or whatever we're calling it in the NDK these days).  Make sure the function exists and your C_LINKAGE macro is doing its job.

Comment: Just updated with something along those lines.

Comment: To be clear, ".so" is shared object, not static object.  The `obj/.../.o` is the compiled .cpp file, the `obj/.../.so` is an intermediate build product, and the `lib/.../.so` is what gets packaged up.  Run `arm-linux-androideabi-nm -D libs/armeabi-v7a/libapplication.so` (where the nm binary lives somewhere under the NDK "toolchains" directory) to see the symbol table.

Comment: If I don't see the function with grep, chances are I won't see it with nm either, how would that help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, the function was throwing an unsatisfied link error because... it was the wrong function. I don't know how, but I had managed to copy and completely lock on the wrong function - nativeVideoPlayerMain, instead of nativePlayerMain. The reason nativeVideoPlayerMain, that I was examining so vigorously was not found in any libraries was because it was in an #ifdef that was never true in both projects. Sorry for wasting everyone's time :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you Java_com_example_xformplayer_DemoRenderer_nativeVideoPlayerMain function lacks a paremeter. 
You can use "javah " to create a correct c header file.

Comment: Well, the thing is I did not write the code, but copied the entire jni directory from a working project into a new one. This function doesn't seem to be defined in any header files (checked with "grep -R "nativeVideoPlayerMain"" in both my and the working project directories), and I'm afraid if I use javah I will cause a lot more damage.

Answer (score 0):

If the function doesn't appear in the final shared library, it's very probably a build issue. There could be several reasons for this:

1) The function is never compiled, e.g. you forgot to list its source file in a LOCAL_SRC_FILES statement. The easiest way to check this is to add a "#error BOOO" in it, then rebuild with ndk-build. It you don't see the corresponding compiler error message, your source file is not compiled.

2) The function is built, but removed from the final shared library because nobody uses it. This can happen if your function is part of a static library that is later linked into your final shared library. By default, the static linker will only pull the symbols from the static library that are effectively used by your shared library's own functions, and their transitive dependencies. One way to prevent this is to use LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES instead of LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES, read $NDK/docs/SANDROID-MK.TXT for a little more details.

Another alternative solution is to move the function definition into the shared library's own source files.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but
1) The source is compiled for sure, because I have another function from that file that works without issues.
2) Some of that is a bit over my head, and I'm not sure how to answer it, but I don't think it is the issue, because as I said, when I grep for the function name in both the working and non-working project directories, I get the same results for where the function is found. Even in the working project the function is not found in the application.so, which really leaves me puzzled.. Can it be added at runtime somehow?