# JNI : Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I am working on application in java.I have use **JNI layer** to communicate **java** with the **C layer**.But while calling the native function in java , the application gives following exception,

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.jni.DeviceCommunicationController.Ivb_GetGain(I)F
at org.jni.DeviceCommunicationController.Ivb_GetGain(Native Method)
at org.jni.GetGain.<init>(GetGain.java:11)
at org.mainWindow.AppWindow$3.stateChanged(AppWindow.java:281)
at javax.swing.JSlider.fireStateChanged(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JSlider$ModelListener.stateChanged(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultBoundedRangeModel.fireStateChanged(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultBoundedRangeModel.setRangeProperties(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultBoundedRangeModel.setValueIsAdjusting(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JSlider.setValueIsAdjusting(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicSliderUI$TrackListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthSliderUI$SynthTrackListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

**Java code**

Function declaration

```
public native float Ivb_GetGain(int gain);
```

Function call

```
// int gain = 13;
new DeviceCommunicationController().Ivb_GetGain(gain);   // here i get the exception
```

**JNI Code**

```
JNIEXPORT jfloat JNICALL   Java_org_jni_DeviceCommunicationController_Ivb_1GetGain
 (JNIEnv *, jobject, jint gain)
   {

  jfloat val = 0;
  val = Syntac_GlobalGain(gain);
  return val;

   }
```

I gone through many links but didn't find the solution.Please help me to find out solution on this ecxeption

Answer (score 1):

You've changed the package name since you generated the .h file with javah. Regenerate it and adjust your .c file accordingly. Note that the package name is encoded in the C function name.

Comment: You've changed the method name. Have a really good look at the method named in the exception and the function declared in your C code.